# Place boxes in center, but align last row to left

Tags: html, css

I can't find how to place boxes in the center but align it to left. It seems that `ul` has width fit not to content, and it is not possible to set it automatically but manually. But I don't want to set it manually, because my content changes dynamically. So I need boxes to be centered but aligned left with no manual changes and no scripts.

Not centered but aligned left:
[image: Not centered but aligned left]

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

ul li {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: wheat;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div>
   <ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
 </ul> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI the thing you are looking for is not left aligned, so if that's the verbiage you're searching for, it makes sense that you are getting confused. "Centered" can be considered short for "center-aligned". So, as written, you are trying to align something both to the left and the center at the same time, which of course is not possible.

Comment: The best way to accomplish this is either CSS Grid layout or flexbox styles, or have a container element that you center and then inside it place your left-aligned UL.

Comment: @TylerH i tried that, ul anyway has width more than it should be (basically fits parent as 100%), and it not possible to center obviously.

Comment: @TylerH he want to place the ul at the center while its content is left aligned BUT the ul need to fit the content which is the tricky part here (or we do it differently)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS grid can do it. Resize the div to see the result:

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 40px); /* width of elements here */
  grid-auto-rows: 40px; /* height here */
  grid-gap: 4px;
  justify-content: center; /* this will do the magic */
}

ul li {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```